# How to write test cases using react-testing-library with the change of useState?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I'm new to unit testing. Currently, I'm working on a react-typescript project that requires me to unit test each component. Here, I'm testing with the if condition and rendering another component in my app in response to the change in useState value.

Here is my app.tsx

```
import ControllerComponent from './controller-component/controller-component';
export interface ControllerWidgetProps {
  title?: string,
  ....
}
export function ControllerWidget(
  props: ControllerWidgetProps
) {
const [value1,setValue1]=useState(-1);
...

return (
    <Card>       
     <Typography >         
         {props.title}
       </Typography>
      <Grid container spacing={1} pt={0} pb={0} sx={{marginTop:-2,marginLeft:-2}}>      
      <Grid  item xs={12} md={2}>      
      <Box>             
       {(value1 == -1)? (
               <ControllerComponent name="xyz"  image="group 55.png"  /> ) : (value1 == 1 ) ? (
              <ControllerComponent name="abc"  image="group 56.png" />):( value1 == 2)) ?(
              <ControllerComponent name="pqr"  image="group 57.png"/):(<></>)}
             </>         
))}

export default UiControllerWidget;
```

Here with the values of `value1` I am passing different props to the `contollerComponent`. So, I just need to test whether the desired props passed with the change of values of `value1`.

Here is my test file

```
describe('UiControllerWidget', () => {
  it('should render successfully', () => {
  const { baseElement } = render(
    <Provider store={store} >  <UiControllerWidget title={''} />  </Provider>);
  expect(baseElement).toBeTruthy();
});

});
```

Can someone help with this case? How to test whether correct component render with `value1`?.Thank you in advance!

Comment: How does you call the `setValue1`?

Comment: `setValue1` is changed with the user input.

Comment: I didn't see it in the code you posted.